# ¿Como puedo pasar datos de un activity a un GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter?

Tags: android-studio

Hola soy nuevo programando en android y estoy trabado en este punto. 
La idea de esta aplicación es que al momento de que se abra el infowindow de un marcador, se muestre información de una base de datos, he estado viendo otras preguntas similares y se que no se puede pasar la informacion por un intent pero si se puede a traves de un metodo pero no se como hacerlo porque la informacion que quiero que aparezca en el infowindow la extraigo de una base de datos a traves de un JSON. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
String regid;

ImageButton btnVoyMap;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;

private TextView mInformationTextView;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> emergenciaList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_emergencias = "http://bomberosemergencias.pe.hu/get_all_emergencias.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "emergencia";

private static final String TAG_HORA = "hora";
private static final String TAG_UBICACION = "ubicacion";
private static final String TAG_TIPO = "tipo";
private static final String TAG_ESTADO = "estado";
private static final String TAG_MAQUINAS = "maquinas";


JSONArray products = null;

ListView lista;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnVoyMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnmap);

    // Hashmap para el ListView
    emergenciaList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAllProducts);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


            // Check device for Play Services APK.
            if (checkPlayServices()) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                regid = getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

                if (regid.isEmpty()) {

                    new RegisterApp(getApplicationContext(), gcm, getAppVersion(getApplicationContext())).execute();
                }

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }


}//fin onCreate

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Antes de empezar el background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...Por favor espere...");
        pDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * obteniendo todos los productos
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_emergencias, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                //Log.i("ramiro", "produtos.length" + products.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable

                    String hora = c.getString(TAG_HORA);
                    String ubicacion = c.getString(TAG_UBICACION);
                    String tipo = c.getString(TAG_TIPO);
                    String estado = c.getString(TAG_ESTADO);
                    String maquinas = c.getString(TAG_MAQUINAS);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    map.put(TAG_HORA, hora);
                    map.put(TAG_UBICACION, ubicacion);
                    map.put(TAG_TIPO, tipo);
                    map.put(TAG_ESTADO, estado);
                    map.put(TAG_MAQUINAS, maquinas);

                    emergenciaList.add(map);
                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        emergenciaList,
                        R.layout.single_post,


                        new String[] {

                                TAG_HORA,
                                TAG_UBICACION,
                                TAG_TIPO,
                                TAG_ESTADO,
                                TAG_MAQUINAS,
                        },
                        new int[] {

                                R.id.single_post_tv_hora,
                                R.id.single_post_tv_ubicacion,
                                R.id.single_post_tv_tipo,
                                R.id.single_post_tv_estado,
                                R.id.single_post_tv_maquinas,

                        });
                // updating listview
                //setListAdapter(adapter);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "EMERGENCIAS ACTUALIZADAS",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
}






private void refresh() {
    finish();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);

       }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
 * <p>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 *         registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(getApplicationContext());
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
 */
private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
    // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

/**
 * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
 */
private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

public void onClickMapa (View view){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.AcercaDe:
            Toast.makeText(this, "DESARROLLADO POR ARQMAS-JMQC-2016",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;


        case R.id.actualizar:
            refresh();

        case R.id.Salir:
            finish();

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

CustomInfoWindowAdapter.java

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

String tipo, hora, ubicacion, estado;

private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
private LayoutInflater inflater;



public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater){
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
    return null;

}



@Override
public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {

    //Carga layout personalizado.
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

    String[] info = m.getTitle().split("&");
    String url = m.getSnippet();


    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tipo)).setText("Accidente vehicular");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.hora)).setText("2017-10-14 04:16:38");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion)).setText("Arevalo");
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.estado)).setText("atendiendo");
    return v;
}




}
```

MapsActivity.class

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    final LatLng arequipa = new LatLng(-16.409896, -71.534169);
    Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(arequipa)
            .title("")
    );

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(arequipa, 17));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new 
   CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this)));
    marcador.showInfoWindow();


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es poder enviar información a tu CustomInfoWindowAdapter para mostrarla, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

Cuando crees el Marker, en su propiedad Tag, puedes pasarle un array de string donde le puedes pasar toda la información que quieras.

Después, en el método getInfoContents de la clase CustomInfoWindowAdapter, recoges ese array de strings y sacas la información.

Puedes hacer:

```
string[] arr = new string[3];
arr[0] = "titulo";
arr[1] = "info1";
arr[2] = "info2";

Marker m = new Marker(...);
m.setTag(arr);
```

y recoger esta información en getInfoContents

```
String[] arr = (String[])m.getTag();
```

Ahora ya tienes la información para poder mostrar lo que quieras:

```
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tipo)).setText(arr[0]);
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.hora)).setText(arr[1]);
((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ubicacion)).setText(arr[2]);
```

Comment: tengo problemas con el `setTag();` y con el `getTag();` dice que no puede resolver el metodo , el marcador no esta creado en el activity principal donde es que recibo la informacion de la base de datos, sino en un MapsActivity.class, lo subi para ver si ayuda a ayudarme..gracias por tu tiempo